# Extension behavior for updated Postgrex version Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir

I have this JSON module

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.Types.JSON do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type

  def type, do: :json

  def cast(term)
      when is_map(term)
        or is_binary(term)
        or is_list(term)
        or is_number(term),
    do: {:ok, term}

  def cast(_), do: :error

  def load(term), do: {:ok, term}

  def dump(term), do: {:ok, term}
end

defmodule EvercamMedia.Types.JSON.Extension do
  alias Postgrex.TypeInfo

  @behaviour Postgrex.Extension

  def init(_parameters, opts),
    do: Keyword.fetch!(opts, :library)

  def matching(_library),
    do: [type: "json", type: "jsonb"]

  def format(_library),
    do: :binary

  def encode(%TypeInfo{type: "json"}, map, _state, library),
    do: library.encode!(map)
  def encode(%TypeInfo{type: "jsonb"}, map, _state, library),
    do: <<1, library.encode!(map)::binary>>

  def decode(%TypeInfo{type: "json"}, json, _state, library),
    do: library.decode!(json)
  def decode(%TypeInfo{type: "jsonb"}, <<1, json::binary>>, _state, library),
    do: library.decode!(json)
end
```

I am getting many warnings as

```
warning: undefined behaviour function decode/1 (for behaviour Postgrex.Extension)
  lib/evercam_media/json.ex:20
warning: undefined behaviour function encode/1 (for behaviour Postgrex.Extension)
  lib/evercam_media/json.ex:20
warning: undefined behaviour function init/1 (for behaviour Postgrex.Extension
```

we are using it for the purpose of handling JSON. I just want to remove those warnings. I know it's for outdated postgrex version, But I want to get rid fo these warnings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the requested by `Postgrex.Extension` behaviour `decode/1` (and `encode/1`, and `init/1`.) If you don’t plan to use it, do e.g.:

```
def decode(_), do: :ok
def encode(_), do: :ok
def init(_), do: :ok
```

The issue here is the [`@behaviour`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-behaviour-notice-the-british-spelling) declares a number of callbacks and this is **the contract** for any implementation. Unless the implementation implements all the callbacks, Elixir compiler issues a warning you get.

Comment: I don't understand, what you said. But, there 2 modules in one file. What I delete the 2nd one. Extension one, is there any harm in that?

Comment: N modules in one file is fine. Your `EvercamMedia.Types.JSON.Extension` declares it implements the behaviour `Postgrex.Extension`. Just put the function ⇑ into this module and the warning will go away.

Comment: For all the requested by the behaviour. You should check _what_ this behaviour defines as callbacks and basically implement all of them. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks, I added those lines before each def, And I am accepting the answer. Just last question: Putting _ and then OK it means everything and anything comes it will say OK? and dont go to next 2 method? of any type , either its decode or encode

Comment: Pattern matching in function clauses is the basement of erlang/elixir language. I would suggest you to read a book rather than asking strangers who btw might be wrong. If your application works properly, then it’s `encode/4` who does the job. `encode/1` would be never called.